# Python, Share a MySQL connection in multiple threads

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

**TL;DR**

In short, I'm trying to open a single MySQL connection and share it with multiple threads, so that each thread creates and uses a cursor, allowing a second query to be placed before the end of the first query.

Is there any library or explanation on how to achieve threadsafety = 2 ([PEP 249](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#threadsafety))?

**Background**

In detail, the behavior I want to achieve is: assuming we have two threads T1 and T2, if T1 executes first a query that takes 10s and T2 executes second a query that takes 1s, T2 should get the result before T1.
This is critical as my application works with thousands of latency-sensitive threads. Each thread can't wait for other threads' queries and it's not possible to open a DB connection for each thread. Using a pool is also limiting, as eventually one thread will have to wait another thread's query (for pool size X, X+1 threads executing a query at the same time will have 1 thread waiting).

I learned that [PEP 249](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#threadsafety) describes what I want to achieve as threadsafety = 2, and that other languages can achieve this behavior just fine. From all the Python <> MySQL libraries I looked into ([mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/), [mysqldb](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/index.html), [pymysql](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/)), all seem to allow only threadsafety = 1. My first question would be: is there any existing library or snippet that achieves threadsafety = 2?

**Progress**

I'm now moving towards overriding the mysql-connector-python library, so that hopefully after hours of painful debugging I can synchronize cursors' and their result sets.

Looks like that whenever a cursor needs to send a command to the socket, I'll have to check if there are any unread/incomplete packets. Meaning that the only moment a thread will have to wait is when there are packets in transit (cursor sending a query or the connection receiving the result of a query).
Afterwards, I'll aim to make sure the correct cursor receives the correct result set.

Behaving as:

```
T1 executes a query -> lock the connection
T2 executes a query -> wait for T1 command to be sent

T1 finishes sending the command -> release the connection
T2 executes a query -> lock the connection and send command

T1 checks for result -> wait for T2 to release the connection lock
T2 finishes sending the command -> release the connection

T1 checks for result -> no result yet
T2 checks for result -> no result yet

Connection receives packets of T2 query after 1s -> read it and store internally

T1 checks for result -> no result yet
T2 checks for result -> gets result from internal storage

Connection receives packets of T2 query after 9s -> read it and store internally
T1 checks for result -> gets result from internal storage
```

Now, I'm aware that other languages achieve this behavior but I'm not familiar with the proper flow.
I'm continuing my research and will keep this post updated.

My second question would be: what is the state-of-the-art approach for a same connection to send two queries from two cursors that race, and get the result in a safe way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't do that. MySQL connections are not, repeat not, thread safe and can't be made so. @romanzh is correct. But using a pool of connections is cheap enough.

Answer (score 1):

For threadsafety it's better not to share single connection between multiple threads. There is a note for example in [MySQLdb documentation](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#mysqldb) that it will upchuck and die. Use the Connection Pool that will handle the connections if it is required by the threads.